# PHPSpec with multiple suites only consider the last one

Tags: php, codeigniter, unit-testing, phpspec

I'm trying to use PHPSpec with multiple suites.

This is needed because my app has several paths that does not necessary mathes a namespace (it's a Code Igniter application).

I've set the `phpspec.yml` like this:

```
suites:
    multi24_libs:
        spec_prefix: "spec\my_app\libraries"
        src_path: "../sistemas/my_app/application/libraries/"

    multi24_models:
        spec_prefix: "spec\my_app\models"
        src_path: "../sistemas/my_app/application/models/"

formatter.name: pretty
```

Whenever I run `./bin/phpspec describe Foo` it whites a test class in `spec/my_app/models/FooSpec`.

After that, even if I move (including namespace) it to `libraries` folder, when phpspec tries to create a new class file or new method (that still doesn't exist) it tries to create under `../sistemas/my_app/application/models/`.

Is there someway to tell phpspec which suite will be used for each class?